# loopback ACL let User role access GET on model but not POST

Tags: node.js, rest, api, acl, loopback

Just found LoopBack, i have been playing around but i can not work out how to restrict User to from POST/GET methods on a model.

I can restrict the user sure but only both POST and GET i would like "users" to access GET when authed this is no worries but how can i restrict the POST on the same end point and then allow user with only certain flag to be able to POST  ?

```
GET /blah
POST /blah
```

So using ACL in loopback i can restrict all methods of the endpoint but not individually control POST and GET ?

Answer (score 0):

To restrict individual POST/GET method, you can validate for an "accessToken" which can be found in "options" of API request and for this, you have to write your endpoint as :

```
YourModel.remoteMethod('methodName', {

    http: {
        verb: 'anyType',
        path: '/dummy'
    },
    accepts: [
        { "arg": "data", "type": "object", "http": { "source": "body" } },
        { "arg": "options", "type": "object", "http": "optionsFromRequest" }
    ],
    returns: {
        arg: 'result',
        type: 'object'
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

For future reference here is the answer for those looking:

To do this you must just use the correct ACCESS TYPE, so instead of ALL, you want:

```
for GET = READ
for POST = EXECUTE
```